Homepage contents and footer suddenly got missing
We are using Magento 2 Community version with Luma theme, our website has been okay for years but we suddenly noticed some contents of the header along with the footer has suddenly gone missing.

Add the screenshot of what is missing from the home page. Also please check the scope of block missing and their visibility
